# Approach to send all users in the database a message?

Tags: mysql, phalcon

I want an admin account to send an announcement to all users in the db.

Right now for my Message table I am storing a message every time for user to user messages with `senderId` and `receiverId` etc.

My problem is can I treat announcement the same way as user to user messages and if yes, would it be wise to save into the message table n times for n number of users in the db every time there is an announcement?

So I want to see if there are cleaner approach to this.

Comment: have messages user specific, have announcements appear in another section of the screen coming from an announcements table perhaps rendering the last few of them with ability to see all. So announcements never make it to the messages table

Comment: What do you mean "tedious", does the MySQL server get bored or something?

Comment: @Vatev No it is probably wrong choice of word so I edited my original question.

Comment: @DrewPierce oh I see so are you suggesting I use an announcement table and just show it to all users instead of saving it together with the messages? I suppose this would be better, thanks.

Comment: i think you will find it better :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much time/effort you want to invest in this.

1. Separate table for announcements: You won't be able to reuse your current messaging system, but you will have maximum flexibility (special GUI features for announcements, they won't get mixed up with normal messages, etc.)
2. Modify your current messaging system to support multi-recipient and/or broadcast messages. With this you can reuse most of your current GUI with some backend modifications.
3. Do the simplest possible thing and send a message to everyone. This is very easy to implement. The obvious downside is that you will have a lot of copied messages in your DB, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks I will consider all of the options.